# How to automatically append updated data

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I am currently working with Azure Data Factory to create pipelines that feed from a dataset into tables located in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. My issue is that whenever new data is fed into my SQL Server database, both the updated and old data is being copied. This is causing my tables to be overpopulated with duplicate data.

Is there any way that I can either append new data onto an existing table or at least have SQL Server automatically overwrite an existing table whenever new data comes in?

I am relatively new to coding, so any expert help would be appreciated.

Thanks